# 2D Arrays in Asembly language

Tags: c++, assembly, multidimensional-array, masm, emu8086

I am trying to convert my C++ code to MASM code.
I got trouble with 2D arrays.

Please help me!

Problem: Find the longest common substrings

My C++ code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
char s[20],t[20];
int b[20][20];
int n,m;
void substr(int i,int j) {
    if (i&&j) {
        if (b[i][j]==1) {
            substr(i-1,j-1);
            printf ("%c",s[i]);
        } else if (b[i][j]==2)
            substr(i-1,j);
        else substr(i,j-1);
    }
}
int main() {
    int f[20][20];
    gets(s+1);
    gets(t+1);
    m=strlen(s+1);
    n=strlen(t+1);
    for (int i=1; i<=m; i++)
        for (int j=1; j<=n; j++)
            if (s[i]==t[j]) {
                f[i][j]=f[i-1][j-1]+1;
                b[i][j]=1;
            } else {
                if (f[i-1][j]>=f[i][j-1]) {
                    f[i][j]=f[i-1][j];
                    b[i][j]=2;
                } else {
                    f[i][j]=f[i][j-1];
                    b[i][j]=3;
                }
            }
    printf("\n::: OUTPUT :::\n");
    if(n==0){
        printf("There is no common substring of S and T!");
    } else {
        printf("The longest substring: \"");
        substr(m,n);
        printf("\".");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And my ASM code:

```
    .model small
; input s, m is lenght of s
    input macro s,m 
        push ax
        push dx                                  
        mov ah, 0Ah 
        lea dx, s
        int 21h                 
        mov al, s + 1 
        xor ah, ah
        mov m, ax
        pop ax
        pop dx     
    endM 
   
    substr macro i,j
        push ax
        push bx
        push cx
    if_s:
    loopij:
        cmp i,0
        jne halt
        cmp j,0
        jne halt
        if_2s:
            cmp b[i][j],1 
            jne else_if
            dec i
            dec j
            substr(i,j)
            lea dx, s[i]
            mov ah, 9
            int 21h
            jmp halt
         else_ifs:
             cmp b[i][j],2
             jne else
             dec i
             substr(i,j)
             jmp halt
          elses:          
             dec j
             substr(i,j)
             jump halt
        jmp loopij 
        ret       
     halt:
     pop ax
     pop bx
     pop cx
endm
.stack 100h
.data 
    newline db 10,13, "$"
    s db  255, ?, 255 dup(0)
    t db  255, ?, 255 dup(0)
    m dw ?
    n dw ?
    i dw ?
    j dw ?
    arr1 db i dup(0)
         db j dup (0)
    arr2 db i dup (0)
         db j dup (0)
.code  
main proc        
    mov  ax,@data
    mov  ds,ax

    input s, m
    call newln
    input t, n
    call newln

    xor ax, ax
    inc ax
    mov i, 2
loopi:
    add ax, m
    cmp i, ax
    ja outloopi
    mov j, 2
loopj:
    mov ax, 1
    add ax, n 
    cmp j, ax
    ja outloopj
    if_:
        mov dx, s[i]
        cmp dx, t[j]
        jne else
        mov cx, f[i-1][j-1]
        mov f[i-1][j-1], cx
        mov b[i][j],1
    else:
        else_if:
            cmp f[i-1][j], f[i][j-1]
            jb else_else
            mov cx,f[i-1][j] 
            mov f[i][j], cx
            mov b[i][j],2
        else_else:
            mov cx,f[i][j-1] 
            mov f[i][j], cx                
            mov b[i][j],3
    jmp loopj
outloopj:
    jmp loopi 
outloopi:       
    substr m, n

    mov  ax,4ch
    int  21h  
main endp

newln proc
    mov ah, 9
    lea dx, newline
    int 21h
    ret
newln endp

end main
```

How to declare a 2D array in ASM?

How to work with 2D arrays in ASM?

Can I convert 2D array into single dimension array in this case?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Memory is linear (i.e. 1d) so we always have to convert 2d or higher into 1d.

Comment: @ErikEidt: If you use a 2-register addressing mode with a static array, you *can* have one be the byte offset to the start of the row, and the other be the byte offset within a row.  But yeah you should be thinking in terms of linear bytes, even if you use separate registers for parts of an addressing mode.

Answer (score 2):

> How to declare a 2D array in ASM?
> How to work with 2D arrays in ASM?

Let's take the example of a 3 X 4 matrix, that's 3 rows by 4 columns.

```
(0,0) (0,1) (0,2) (0,3)    <- 1st row
(1,0) (1,1) (1,2) (1,3)    <- 2nd row
(2,0) (2,1) (2,2) (2,3)    <- 3rd row

  ^     ^     ^     ^
 1st   2nd   3rd   4th
 col   col   col   col
```

Assuming that the elements are to be **byte-sized**, all it takes is writing:

```
MyArray db 3*4 dup (0)
```

This sets aside a 12-byte block of memory. The special nature of it being a 2-dimensional array purely comes from how you, the programmer, will interact with it and interpret its content.

Looking at the matrix in **row-order**:

```
| MyArray
|
<        row 0        > <        row 1        > <        row 2        >
----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- -----
(0,0) (0,1) (0,2) (0,3) (1,0) (1,1) (1,2) (1,3) (2,0) (2,1) (2,2) (2,3)
```

Below is how you address any element of the array.

```
OffsetInTheArray = (RowIndex * NumberOfColumns + ColumnIndex) * BytesPerElement
```

The assignment `MyArray[Row][Col] = 1` in emu8086 style:

```
mov     ax, Cols      ; CONST, (Cols equ ...)
mul     Row
add     ax, Col
;;;shl     ax, 1      ; Only for word-sized elements
mov     bx, ax
mov     byte ptr MyArray[bx], 1
```

Looking at the matrix in **column-order**:

```
| MyArray
|
<     col 0     > <     col 1     > <     col 2     > <     col 3     >
----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- -----
(0,0) (1,0) (2,0) (0,1) (1,1) (2,1) (0,2) (1,2) (2,2) (0,3) (1,3) (2,3)
```

Below is how you address any element of the array.

```
OffsetInTheArray = (ColumnIndex * NumberOfRows + RowIndex) * BytesPerElement
```

The assignment `MyArray[Row][Col] = 1` in emu8086 style:

```
mov     ax, Rows      ; CONST, (Rows equ ...)
mul     Col
add     ax, Row
;;;shl     ax, 1      ; Only for word-sized elements
mov     bx, ax
mov     byte ptr MyArray[bx], 1
```

### Unrelated to the question concerning the 2-D arrays, but very important nonetheless.

> ```
> input macro s,m 
>   push ax
>   push dx                                  
>   ...
>   pop ax
>   pop dx
> endM
> ```

You must restore these registers in reverse order! The stack is a last-in-first-out (LIFO) structure:

```
push    ax
push    dx
...
pop     dx
pop     ax
```

---

> ```
> substr macro i,j
>   push ax
>   push bx
>   push cx
>   ...
>   pop ax
>   pop bx
>   pop cx
> endm
> ```

Here also you must restore these registers in reverse order. And just as important, seeing that *substr* is meant to be a **recursive procedure**, you should not turn this into a macro.

---

> ```
> cmp i,0
> jne halt
> cmp j,0
> jne halt
> ```

This snippet is not a correct translation of `if (i&&j)`. It's quite the opposite:

```
cmp     i, 0
je      halt
cmp     j, 0
je      halt
```

---

> ```
> mov  ax,4ch
> int  21h
> ```

The DOS function number goes into the `AH` register. Your instruction places it into `AL`.

```
mov     ax, 4C00h   ; DOS.TerminateWithReturnCode
int     21h
```

---

> ```
> lea dx, s[i]
> mov ah, 9
> int 21h
> ```

This will not work like in `printf ("%c",s[i])`. The DOS.PrintString function 09h expects `DX` to point at a **$**-terminated string. Another DOS function can do it though:

```
mov     bx, i
mov     dl, s[bx+2] 
mov     ah, 02h     ; DOS.PrintCharacter
int     21h
```

In case you're wondering about the `+2`, well you have obtained the string *s* from using the DOS.BufferedInput function 0Ah which has returned the characters at offset 2 from the buffer that you named *s*. You will have to watch out for this at numerous places.

Next is a quick solution to the problem:

```
  db      255, 0
s db      255 dup (0)
  ...
  lea     dx, s-2
  mov     ah, 0Ah   ; DOS.BufferedInput
  int     21h
```

There are additional problems in this code but I think that with all of the above you should be able to write a first attempt. And with that code you can always come back...